# How to use QVirtualKeyboard plugin without using QML?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtplugin

I have X_Compiled Qt for BeagleBone Black and everything works fine. I've compiled Qt virtual keyboard plugin and I can load keyboard example on the device. I want to use this virtual keyboard in my C++ app. Can anyone show me the right way to do so?

I've also downloaded a [plugin](http://tolszak-dev.blogspot.nl/2013/04/qplatforminputcontext-and-virtual.html) and compiled it but I don't know how to use it. Can any one tell me how to use Qt plugins like the two I mentioned above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all make sure that the plugin is in the plugin folfer of Qt installation path and in main file add this line before creating QApplication object.

```
qputenv("QT_IM_MODULE", QByteArray("qtvirtualkeyboard"));
```

Comment: Any reason keyboard is acting as disabled?
It does show when field get focus but it doesn't respond to clicks on the buttons.

Comment: @PredragManojlovic, Is there any validator or inputMask set on the field you are trying to insert text?

Comment: nope. Simple input field. Is it maybe limited not to respond on mouse clicks? Does it work only on touch events?